# Why is omp critical needed here?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

```
void main()
{
    int i, n;
    double A[N], B[N];
    printf(“Give threads number\n”);
    scanf(“% d”, &n);
    omp_set_num_threads(n);
    /*Assume that array A is initialized here*/
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
        B[i] = A[i];
    #pragma omp parallel private(i) shared(A)
    {
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
        for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
            #pragma omp critical
            A[i] = (A[i] + B[i + 1]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why #pragma omp critical in needed here?
Since we use  #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) shouldn't each thread handle different loop iterations
and since we only access B arrays data and do not alter the data, there shouldn't be a race condition right?
So doesn't critical just stall the program for no reason?

Comment: Who says it's needed?

Comment: I saw it as a solution to an exercise on how to use openmp to make a program parallel and I assumed it was needed but I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: There is a lot of bad tutorials. Where specifically did you find this?

Comment: Please consider checking your sources. From what I can see it is not only unecessary but it also kill performance by making the loop sequential and adding a huge overhead (so the final code will be much slower than the initial serial one)